# RPC error when interacting with contract using Ganache GUI, but it works fine when using Ganache CLI

Tags: truffle, metamask

I have a truffle project, if I migrate it onto ganache-cli and then interact with my contract (via Metamask) it works great. But if I try and do the exact same thing using ganahe-gui the contract deploys fine, but interacting with it fails.

This is the error:

```
Error: [ethjs-rpc] rpc error with payload {"id":406503133755,"jsonrpc":"2.0","params":["0xf8ab06843b9aca008303cb1794071faee0d32e420c88295802a65758a924b5626201b844d6febde800000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000822d45a087a8df0b863c944ad2f79551800f21289efac79e74d62a8b0c3d7d5580ec4df5a01d92fd24ee5a418df0184bc61db21dd36719ce2a234d11638e092a9c4eb08bca"],"method":"eth_sendRawTransaction"} [object Object
```

This is not anything to do with my contract code or it would not work with the cli. I think the problem may be metamask? I am using the same 'chain' on Metmask for both gui and cli- localhost:8545. Metamask is detecting the chain properly because I can see that I have 100 ether (99.9 after contract deployment).

Metmask does not give any errors prior to submitting the tx, it is only when I press Send that it gives me the error. If it wasn't detecting the chain, I wouldn't be able to send as I'd have a 0 balance.

Wat do?

Comment: A wild guess: ganache-cli has your account unlocked on the node, so you can send a raw transaction without signing it with your private key (ganache-cli signs it for you), while Ganache does not have your account unlocked on the node, so you must sign the transaction yourself before sending it.

Comment: How would I test if this was the case or not?

Comment: I don't know ganache, but ganache-cli starts by printing all unlocked accounts on your terminal. Maybe you can find where ganache does the same.

Comment: I had the exact same issue, resetting my Metamask account worked. Thank you :)

Answer (score 4):

The answer is: I need to reset metamask between sessions:

Settings > advanced > Reset Account

Not sure why this is needed for ganache gui but not ganache cli!

Comment: I needed to do this with ganache-cli as well when I resetted the blockchain state by clearing the files where blockchain is stored. Metamask seems to not detect the blockchain state is changed and therefore sends wrong parameters in calls.